# How to draw a header in my own widget in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget, draw

Does anyone know how to draw a header (and other simple elements), just like in, for example, QTreeWidget, in my own widget?
I would like to use style and call something like:
drawElement(CE_Header, rect, painter);
to draw standard header in specified rect.

QStyle::drawControl can't do it, because it draws control over whole widget.

Qt documentation doesn't say much about it.

Comment: did you check QHeaderView documentation?

Comment: Found it, I can use drawControl spefying rect in options.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `QHeaderView` and reimplement the `paint` method, inside there you can use the `QStyleOption` data.  Then use `QTreeWidget::setHeader(QHeaderView* header)` to set your header in the widget.

Comment: Sorry, when you said "just like in, for example, QTreeWidget, in my own widget", I assumed you were subclassing some sort of view.